# How to get the indexes of column and row in a 2-dimensional matrix(list) that have the most given elements in using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

For example, I have a 2-dimensional matrix:

```
[0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0

 0 5 0 0 5 0 0 0

 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0

 5 0 0 0 5 0 0 5

 0 5 0 0 0 0 5 0]
```

I want to get the indexes of the row and column with the most 5s. Which should be the third row and fifth column. I don't want to use for loop to get that because it cost too much time; is there anyway to solve it using numpy module in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way. `a` is the array and `elem` is the element to be checked:

```
In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]])

In [72]: elem = 5
```

This gives the (first) column with the most occurrences of `elem`:

```
In [73]: (a == elem).sum(axis=0).argmax()
Out[73]: 5
```

This gives the (first) row with the most occurrences of `elem`:

```
In [74]: (a == elem).sum(axis=1).argmax()
Out[74]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact this way is faster

Answer (score 1):

```
colnum = np.argmax([list(a[:,x]).count(5) for x in range(a.shape[1])])

colnum
Out[22]: 4

rownum = np.argmax([list(a[x,:]).count(5) for x in range(a.shape[0])])

rownum
Out[25]: 2
```

Number starts from 0

Comment: Thanks this helps!

Comment: @GeorgeSha Glad to hear:) Basically I'm using `list comprehension` here to count the number of occurrence of `5` on each row/columns. `list(a[x,:]).count(5)` here will convert the `numpy.array` to `list` and use the python built-in function `count()`. Eventually, I use `np.argmax` to find the indices of the maximum values along the list